# How to create a new column based on conditions on other column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, indexing, concatenation

I want to take first five digits from column C if there is word "US" in column B else take all the digits from column C.Required outputs are in column "OUTPUT".

```
A          B          C         OUTPUT
hell       US         12234455  12234
mell       UK         12345666  12345666
shall      US         21248075  21248
pel      SPAIN        90056784  90056784
wel        SP         35455689  35455689
shel       US         12095678  12095
```

I am using the following codes but its not working.Please help.Dataset name=sf1

```
if sf1.B.all=="US":
   sf1['OUTPUT'] = sf1['C'].astype(str).str[:5]
else:
   sf1['OUTPUT'] = sf1['C'].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `numpy where`:

```
import numpy as np

sf1['OUTPUT'] = np.where(sf1['B'].eq('US'), sf1['C'].astype(str).str[:5], sf1['C'])
```

or `pandas where`:

```
sf1['OUTPUT'] = sf1['C'].astype(str).str[:5].where(sf1['B'].eq('US'), sf1['C'])
```

or `pandas loc`:

```
sf1.loc[sf1['B'].eq('US'), 'OUTPUT'] = sf1['C'].astype(str).str[:5]
sf1.loc[sf1['B'].ne('US'), 'OUTPUT'] = sf1['C']
```

**Output:**

```
        A       B          C      OUTPUT
0    hell      US   12234455       12234
1    mell      UK   12345666    12345666
2   shall      US   21248075       21248
3     pel   SPAIN   90056784    90056784
4     wel      SP   35455689    35455689
5    shel      US   12095678       12095
```

Answer (score 3):

To accomplish this, we’ll use numpy’s built-in where() function. This function takes three arguments in sequence: the condition we’re testing for, the value to assign to our new column if that condition is true, and the value to assign if it is false.
[source](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/tutorial-add-column-pandas-dataframe-based-on-if-else-condition/)

```
stf1['OUTPUT'] = np.where(df['B'] == 'US', df['C'].astype(str).str[:5], df['C'])
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Let us try `mask`

```
df['OUTPUT'] = df.C.mask(df.B.eq('US'),lambda x : x.astype(str).str[:5])
df
Out[30]: 
       A      B         C    OUTPUT
0   hell     US  12234455     12234
1   mell     UK  12345666  12345666
2  shall     US  21248075     21248
3    pel  SPAIN  90056784  90056784
4    wel     SP  35455689  35455689
5   shel     US  12095678     12095
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also employ the apply function as follows:

```
df['Output'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.C[:5] if row.B == 'US' else row.C, axis = 1)
```

this produces:

```
    A   B   C   Output
0   hell    US  12234455    12234
1   mell    UK  12345666    12345666
2   shall   US  21248075    21248
3   pel     SPAIN   90056784    90056784
4   wel     SP  35455689    35455689
5   shel    US  12095678    12095
```